# How to identify and exclude transaction reversals in SQL

Tags: sql-server

In my dataset I would like to identify and exclude transaction reversals. Please see example highlighted below where invoice_id 789123 should net to 0 and therefore be excluded from the final report.

[image]

Therefore i should only see the following rows in my extract:

[image]

To get to this extract I used the following code to identify duplicate payments:

```
select 
    [Vendor ID],
    [Invoice_ID],
    [Clearing Document],
    [Clearing date], 
    [Amount], 
    [record_count] 
from
 (
 select * ,
    COUNT([Vendor ID]) 
    OVER
         (
         PARTITION BY 
         [Vendor ID],
         [Invoice_ID],
         [Clearing Document],
         [Clearing date], 
         [Amount]
         ) AS record_count
 from dbo.table
 ) AS duplicatepay
 where record_count > 1 and [Amount] <> 0
```

Can someone help me edit the above code to exclude transaction reversals that net to 0 as I can't seem to find a way. Thanks!

Comment: This looks more SQLServer than MySQL ___Please dont spam tags___

Comment: What about `and [duplicatepay].[Amount] > 0` instead of `<> 0`

Comment: That wouldn't show me if a particular invoice had an amount reversal

Comment: Seems like you also want a windowed `SUM` in your subquery, and then you should be checking if the value of *that* is `0`.

Comment: Though, looking at the sample data, why would any of those rows appear *other* than the ones you don't want to (with the query you have probided)? The `COUNT` of those rows will all be `1`... You `PARTITION BY` `amount`, and those rows have "unique" values for `amount` in your sample data.

Comment: .. ) AS record_count, sum(amount) over (partition by vendor_id, invoice_id) as total_amount .... where .. and total_amount <> 0

Answer (score 0):

You can define groups of rows to exclude using the count and sum functions in CTE, and then reject all inappropriate rows.

```
With CTE AS (
select 
    [Vendor ID],
    [Invoice_ID],
    [Clearing Document],
    [Clearing date], 
    [Amount],
    COUNT(*) Over (Partition by [Vendor ID], [Invoice_ID], [Clearing Document], [Clearing date]) As CNT,
    SUM([Amount]) Over (Partition by [Vendor ID], [Invoice_ID], [Clearing Document], [Clearing date]) AS SUMM
from dbo.tbl
)
Select *
From CTE
Where NOT(CNT>1 And SUMM=0)
```